# Fourier expansion of Dedekind eta function with rational arguments

Tags: series-expansion, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I want to be able to compute the Fourier series expansion in q=Exp[2πiz] for DedekindEta[(az+b)/(cz+d)] with integer a,b,c,d, but not requiring ad-bc=1.  Just replacing z in terms of q and doing Series does not work.  Is there some way to make this work?

Comment: Paste code what have you tried?

Comment: Please give an example of $a,b,c,d$ that you are interested in and what expansion you expect to get in that case.